# How to redirect just homepage to unique url with .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect 'packagingindustry.fraingroup.com' to 'fraingroup.com/blog' but there are several links within 'packagingindustry.fraingroup.com' that I want to redirect to just 'fraingroup.com' without the trailing slug 'blog.'

How do I uniquely just redirect the home url to include 'blog' while if any other permalinks containing any slugs (e.g. - 'packagingindustry.fraingroup.com/blog-title') redirecting to fraingroup.com (e.g. - 'fraingroup.com/blog-title')

These are the two redirect statements I'm working with:

```
# Redirect /index.php 'www.fraingroup.com/blog/'
# Redirect 301 / 'fraingroup.com/'
```

Comment: RTFM: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect   `The new URL may be either an absolute URL beginning with a scheme and hostname, or a URL-path beginning with a slash. In this latter case the scheme and hostname of the current server will be added.`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(index\.php)?$ http://fraingroup.com/blog
```

The `Redirect` directive will also redirect everything after the match, so `/` redirects pretty much the entire site. However, with regex and `RedirectMatch`, you can limit to just an exact match.